# Spring Security requires login despite permitAll()

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Angular on the frontend and Spring Boot on the backend.

My registration page works and I can successfully create a user and save it to my PostgreSQL database. However, my problem arises with the 2-factor authentication during login. After clicking "Submit" and the OTP code is sent to the email, the user is redirected to the 2FA page where they can enter the code. Up until that point, everything works fine.

As a beginner programmer, I would greatly appreciate it if you could explain your answers a bit.

However, after entering the code and clicking "Submit" again, the following error message appears:

```
"HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: 'OK',
url: 'http://localhost:8080/login', ok: false, …}
error: 
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse 

[[Prototype]]: Object
headers: HttpHeaders
lazyInit: () => {…}
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: Map(0) {size: 0}[[Prototype]]
: Objectmessage: 
"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/login"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: false
status: 200statusText: "OK"url: "http://localhost:8080/login"
```

Attached is my code. If you need me to provide additional code snippets, please let me know.<

LoginController

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/login")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    @PostMapping()
    public LoginResponse login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest)   {
        return loginService.login(loginRequest);
    }

    @PostMapping("/validateOtp")
    public LoginResponse validateOtp(@RequestBody ValidateOtpRequest validateOtpRequest)    {
        return loginService.validateOtp(validateOtpRequest);
    }

    @PostMapping("/logout")
    public LoginResponse logout(@RequestBody LogoutRequest logoutRequest)    {
        return loginService.logout(logoutRequest);
    }

}
```

ValidateOtpRequest:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class ValidateOtpRequest {

    private String sessionId;
    private String otp;
}
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    private final AppUserService appUserService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v*/login/validateOtp").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }


    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(appUserService);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","PUT"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

otp.model.ts

```
export class OTP {
  sessionId: string | undefined;
  otp: string | undefined;
}
```

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from './user.model';
import {OTP} from "./otp.model";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  createUser(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "registration", user);
  }

  loginUser(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "login", user);
  }

  validateOTP(otp: OTP) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "login/validateOtp", otp);
  }

}
```

two-factor.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {OTP} from "../otp.model";
import {UserService} from "../user.service";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-two-factor',
  templateUrl: './two-factor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./two-factor.component.css']
})
export class TwoFactorComponent {

  otp: OTP = new OTP();

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router) { };


  onSubmit() {
    this.userService.validateOTP(this.otp).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('OTP sended');
    });
  }
}
```

My Postman requests in the backend were successful. There, I was able to register the user, log in, and confirm the OTP code.

Comment: It doesn't look like you should have `.anyRequest().authenticated()`.

Comment: @Unmitigated Thank you for your quick response. Unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).